# How to store dropdown selected value in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have form and each and every input values I want to store in divs when it enters.

I did it for input box like this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('ref7').innerHTML = this.value" name="bank_name" id="bank_name" id="bank_name">
```

but how can I proceed it to dropdown box selected values ?

this is my select box

```
  <select class="select form-control" id="payment" required name="payment" onkeyUp="document.getElementById('ref14').innerHTML = this.value">
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select</option>
                        <option value="As per signed contract accpetable">
                            As per signed contract acceptable
                        </option>
                        <option value="As per contract not accpetable">
                            As per contract not acceptable (please specifiy the fee below)
                        </option>
                    </select>

<div id="ref14"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `select` instead of `onkeyUp` event use `onchange` event.

[**Reference**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla  sorry its not me.i don't have enough reputation for voting :(

Comment: @Tharuperera..glad that the answer worked for you..happy to help you..;)